# Simple GUI with list and add item

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a simple GUI in java's swing library which contains a list of items (items of a specific class). I also want a box besides the list with a text field and a button for adding a new item to the list (this item would then have the content in the text field as its title). I've looked around but not found a decent tutorial for this. Any link to proper tutorials or a brief example is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [How to create GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, but of course formatting it to your needs. You would also need to add action listeners to the button. If you do not know how to do this, I can show you.

You could use and adapt the code example below, or you can use this tutorial to teach you everything you need to know about Swing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

This example was generated using NetBeans Gui Builder.

```
public class NewJFrame15 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame15
 */
public NewJFrame15() {
    initComponents();
}                    
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));

    jButton1.setText("Add");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 114, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 133, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 335, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame15.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame15.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame15.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame15.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame15().setVisible(true);
            Math.random();
        }
    });
}                 
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JList jList1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;       
}
```

Comment: This is terrific! Now that I am to add an item though. I'm familiar with how I add an action listener to the button. But the current items are stored in the String array "strings", how do I actually add a new element to that array?

Comment: What you do is first, keep a string array containing your list entries somewhere in your class, then each time you need to change the list inside it, update that list reference, and call `list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {// inner class})` and follow the template for setting the list model, but just reference the `strings` variable to your stored string array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JCheckBoxes to select specific items or a JComboBox for a drop down menu. Constructors are available  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ here.

Also, the add item http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29 method allows you to use text field input for your JComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with the textbox and button and writing the results to the screen or to the log to see that it's working.
http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jtextfield-class-example

Then work on displaying a list, and refresh the list with the data in the textbox as a last step.
Lists (note the "Adding Items to and Removing Items from a List" section): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html